# does gmaps support callback option

Tags: json, google-maps

i want to get the cities list around a place defined with latitude and longitude
here is the simple code i use:

```
JSON.stringify = JSON.stringify || function (obj) {
    var t = typeof (obj);
    alert(t);
    if (t != "object" || obj === null) {
        if (t == "string") obj = '"'+obj+'"';
            return String(obj);
    } else {
        var n, v, json = [], arr = (obj && obj.constructor == Array);
        for (n in obj) {
            v = obj[n]; t = typeof(v);
            if (t == "string") v = '"'+v+'"';
            else if (t == "object" && v !== null) v = JSON.stringify(v);
            json.push((arr ? "" : '"' + n + '":') + String(v));
        }
        return (arr ? "[" : "{") + String(json) + (arr ? "]" : "}");
    }
}
function insertReply(content) {
    var JSONString = JSON.stringify(content);
    document.body.innerHTML += JSONString;
    alert(JSONString);
}
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    var url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=false&callback=insertReply";
    script.src = (url);
    document.body.appendChild(script);
```

but it seems that google maps doesnt support the callback option (...&callback=insertReply)
is the a solution for that?
thank you in advance..

Answer (score 0):

It's not supported.

Use the [gecoding-service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) of the Maps-Javascript-API instead.